# Having trouble making a SOAP proxy / client using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I have the following web-service endpoint address:

```
https://*.*.*/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?channel=:TrackTrace:DTHZCOMSD_PI_TRACKTRACE_TRANSP
```

These are the steps I'm performing.

- In my project I go to References -> Add Service Reference.
- In Address field I enter the address above.
- VS says: "VS has detected a problem with the site's security certificate"
- I confirm this exception.
- VS says that the service requires a username and password and asks for a Discovery Credential.
- Entering the username/password combination that was provided.
- Confirming.
- Getting this:

> The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://*.*.*/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?channel=:TrackTrace:DTHZCOMSD_PI_TRACKTRACE_TRANSP'.
>   The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Basic realm="XISOAPApps"'. The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized. If the service is defined in the current solution, try
>   building the solution and adding the service reference again.

If instead of adding a Service Reference I'll go References -> Add Service Reference ->  Advanced -> Add Web Reference and enter the address above, I will be asked to accept the certificate and authenticate again. After confirming I will get a webpage:

> Message Servlet is in Status OK Status information: Servlet
>   com.sap.aii.af.mp.soap.web.MessageServlet (Version $Id:
>   //tc/xi/NW04S_18_REL/src/_adapters/_soap/java/com/sap/aii/af/mp/soap/web/MessageServlet.java#1
>   $) bound to /MessageServlet  Classname ModuleProcessor: null 
>   Lookupname for localModuleProcessorLookupName:
>   localejbs/ModuleProcessorBean  Lookupname for
>   remoteModuleProcessorLookupName: null  ModuleProcessorClass not
>   instantiated  ModuleProcessorLocal is Instance of
>   com.sap.aii.af.mp.processor.ModuleProcessorLocalLocalObjectImpl0_0 
>   ModuleProcessorRemote not instantiated

and the following text:

> The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information

Any hints on what could be wrong?

**EDIT 1:** I can call the service from SOAPSonar (using a wsdl file provided) setting Basic Authentication. If I use the same WSDL to generate a proxy with svcutils the resulting code:

```
var serviceClient = new DTHZCOMSD_PI_TRACKTRACE_TRANSPClient();
serviceClient.Open();
ZCOMSD_PI_TRACKTRACE_TRANSPResponse response;
response = serviceClient.DTHZCOMSD_PI_TRACKTRACE_TRANSP(request)
```

fails with the following errors:

> {"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure."} The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish
>   trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

(The certificate was imported into Windows)
How can I bypass it ?
And how can I add username/password for simple authentication for the code that was generated by svcutil?

**EDIT2:**

I was able to add a Service Reference by passing a wsdl document directly to VS (instead of passing the service URL). Got a few problems with certification and authorization.

The credentials problem was solved pretty fast:
code:

```
service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");  
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
```

and app.config

```
<binding>
...
<transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />

<message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />

...
</binding>
```

Certification took a bit longer.
I tried to change the certification mode for a single service, but it didn't work.
Any idea why?

```
service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

Unfortunately, the only way to bypass it for now is to trust all certificates this way:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

Still looking for a way to change the certification mode for a single service.